# Retrieve surface of street OSM R

Tags: r, openstreetmap, surface

I have a tibble in R with two columns: Name of the street, Town.
For a project I would like to get the surface of the street. I would like to know if it's surface is asphalt, paved etc.

I came up with:

```
  library(OpenStreetMap)
  library(lubridate)
  library(ggmap)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(tidyverse)

  get_surface <- function(town, street) {
  dat <- opq(town) %>%
    add_osm_feature(key = 'surface') %>%
    osmdata_sf()
  i <- which(dat$osm_lines$name == street)
  Surface <- dat$osm_lines[i, ]
  return(Surface[which(!is.na(Surface)), ])
}
surfaces <- map2(unique_street_town$Town, unique_street_town$Street, get_surface)
```

This takes a lot of time because it is a large tibble. Is there a function I could use?

My tibble looks like
Street                  Town
Goeman Borgesiuslaan    Groningen
Esserhaag               Haren

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please also add the packages you are using to your code (`library(...)`) since we need a minimal reproducible code example to provide answers. Please also add some example data (eg. via R code created with `dput`) THX :-)

Comment: I'm not sure there is a function but could speed up your function. You are doing a separate online OSM lookup for each call with `opq()` - can you just do one for each town, and then analyse all the streets at once? Also `is.na(Surface)` will probably slow it down as `Surface` is a tibble, which is not what `is.na` is intended for - you perhaps want `!is.na(Surface$surface)`.

Comment: Perhaps this question should be asked to the author of the (OSM) package since it requires a) support for bulk web queries against the web API and b) support for vectorized ("n rows in the vector") `add_osm_feature` calls